# How to calculate throughput based on wireshark

Tags: awk, network-protocols, wireshark, throughput

You know ping is part of  ICMP protocol. I want to calculate throughput based on these ICMP message. The way is calculate Number of this ICMP meesage multiple number of bite of ICMP packet divide by total time. Is there any thing in wireshark inordetr to do that? If not what is your suggestion is there any thing like linux awk in win 7 to work with it by exporting wireshark log to txt file.

Comment: Have you read the FAQ ? Whe help people having problem with some code. Where's yours ?

Comment: Install cygwin, including the gawk package.

Comment: @EdMorton, yes I think there is no way but I am not sure. As you say just work with txt file by awk is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply get the number of ICMP ping request packets through wireshark filters. Multiply  it with the default [ping packet size](http://www.ehow.com/how_8735878_set-ping-packet-size.html) and then divide by the total time.

Answer (score 2):

Click
Statistics => Summary (This gives average throughput)
Statistics => IO Graph (This has options which gives you instantaneous throughput)